# django accept data from angularJS is not valid

Tags: python, django, angularjs

I use `angularJS` `$http` send data to django and the method is `POST`
this is my `controller.js`

```
  registerApp.controller('registerCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submitRegisterForm = function() {
      if ($scope.registerForm.$valid) {
        console.log($scope.user);
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '.',
          data: $scope.user,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
        });
      } else {
        return console.log(3333);
      }
    };
  });
```

this is my `views.py` in django

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    print request.POST
```

but the result of print is

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"username":"bob","password1":"123123","password2":"123123","email":"cot@q.com"}': [u'']}>
```

why the data is a Key of the dict?
and wher is the `[u'']` come from??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you've called it form-encoded data, doesn't mean it actually is. In fact it looks like you're posting JSON. Drop that header and get the data by doing `json.loads(request.body)`.